# How to wait for URLSession Request to finish before rendering a SwiftUI Sheet View?

Tags: swift, api, rest, swiftui, urlsession

Noob here.

I'm making a lyrics search app that simply uses an API which receives a song name along with an artist name and simply returns the lyrics. I basically have two questions:

**First one Being**: Im having trouble showing a new Sheet with information that comes from the API. So my code works as follows: From the View, press a button which, if the user is connected to the internet, call a method that does the whole API calling, creates a SongDetails object with all the info on that song(name, artist and lyrics) and add it to the @Published searchedSongs array (previously checking the same song hasnt been searched before). Once that is done, I want the sheet to show the lyrics from that array.
My problem is the app crashes with an error of IndexOutOfRange when I want to access the searchedSongs array from the view since it seems its not actually waiting for the SongDetails object to be fully added to the array before rendering the sheet. This seems to be some sort of concurrency problem I guess. Is there any way to only show the sheet once the SongDetails object has been added to the array? My current code is:

**HomeView.swift**

```
HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            if(!NetworkMonitor.shared.isConnected) {
                                self.noConnectionAlert.toggle()
                            } else {
                                viewModel.loadApiSongData(songName: songName, artistName: artistName)
                                self.showingLyricsSheet = true
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            CustomButton(sfSymbolName: "music.note", text: "Search Lyrics!")
                        })
                       
                        .alert(isPresented: $noConnectionAlert) {
                                    Alert(title: Text("No internet connection"), message: Text("Oops! It seems you arent connected to the internet. Please connect and try again!"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
                                }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingLyricsSheet) {
                        LyricsView(vm: self.viewModel, songName: songName, artistName: artistName)
                    }
```

**ViewModel.swift**

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var searchedSongs = [SongDetails]()
    func loadApiSongData(songName: String, artistName: String) {
        let rawUrl = "https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/\(artistName)/\(songName)"
        let fixedUrl = rawUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        print("Old url: \(rawUrl)")
        print("New url: \(fixedUrl!)")
        
        guard let url = URL(string: fixedUrl!) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Song.self, from: data) {
                    // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // update our UI
                        print("Good. Lyrics:")
                        if(!self.songAlreadySearched(songName: songName)) {
                            let song = SongDetails(songName: songName, artistName: artistName, lyrics: decodedResponse.lyrics)
                            self.searchedSongs.append(song)
                        }
                    }
                    // everything is good, so we can exit
                    return
                }
            }

            // if we're still here it means there was a problem
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            
        }.resume()
    }
```

**LyricsView.swift**

```
ScrollView {
                    Text(vm.searchedSongs[0].lyrics)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
```

**Second one:** Im having a hard time understanding how URLSession handles error cases. If for whatever reason (say I submit "asd" as song name and "fds" as artist name) the api fails to retrieve the lyrics, how can I know that from the view and be able to not even show the lyrics sheet in the first place since there wont be any lyrics to show at all.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your URLSession question should probably be split into its own question. It could also use some more detail when you do so, like if you mean error cases such as HTTP errors or if there are certain responses you getting from the API endpoint (ie different JSON values) that represent errors.

Comment: Thank you! Ive made a separate question in case you feel like taking a quick look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't include enough code that I can show you *exactly* what to do, but I can give you the general steps.

1. Don't set `showingLyricsSheet` directly after your `loadApiSongData` call. `loadApiSongData` is asynchronous, so this will practically guarantee that the sheet will be shown before the API call loads. Instead, bind the sheet's presentation to a variable on your view model that only gets set once the API request has finished. I'd recommend using the `sheet(item:)` form instead of `sheet(isPresented:)` in order to avoid pitfalls that are common with getting the most recently-updated values in the sheet.
2. Instead of having `LyricsView` access `vm.searchedSongs`, perhaps pass the songs directly as a parameter to `LyricsView`. Again, this would be easy with the strategy from #1 (including using `sheet(item:)`).

Here's a simple mockup illustrating the concepts from #1 and #2:

```
struct APIResponse : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var apiValues : [String] = []
}

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var apiResponse : APIResponse?
    
    func apiCall() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.apiResponse = APIResponse(apiValues: ["Testing","1","2","3"])
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world")
            .sheet(item: $viewModel.apiResponse) { item in
                LyricsView(lyrics: item.apiValues)
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.apiCall()
            }
    }
}

struct LyricsView : View {
    var lyrics : [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(lyrics.joined(separator: ", "))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The sheet works as expected now and renders only when the request has finished! Thanks! 

Im having another issue though, Ill elaborate on the following pastebin since Im short on characters:

https://pastebin.com/uk8QhR7F

Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Can use click the green checkmark to mark the answer as correct/accepted? You can also use the arrow to upvote if it was helpful. Regarding your question in the pastebin, I suggest you use the same sheet(item:) strategy I use above. It should solve the blank lyrics view issue.

Comment: Absolutely! Consider it done. And by the way, using sheet(item:) solved it once again. Cant thank you enough :). Feel free to look into my other question whenever you have 2mins!

Comment: Looks like you already got a response to that one, but let me know if it doesn't fit your needs and I can try to come up with something else.